# react native posts error: can't find module 'prepack'

Tags: react-native

I want to package react native bundle

```
react-native bundle --entry-file index.ios.js --bundle-output ../NovaWed/NovaWed/Business/ReactNativeBundle/index.ios.jsbundle --platform ios --assets-dest ../NovaWed/NovaWed/Business/ReactNativeBundle --prepack true
```

But terminal posts error like this:

> Error: Cannot find module 'prepack'
>       at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:326:15)
>       at Function.Module._load (module.js:277:25)
>       at Module.require (module.js:354:17)
>       at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
>       at PrepackBundle.build (/Users/huangjunjie/Documents/Work/wed-iphone-nova/wed-react-native/node_modules/react-native/packager/react-packager/src/Bundler/PrepackBundle.js:65:19)
>       at Object.savePrepackBundle [as save] (/Users/huangjunjie/Documents/Work/wed-iphone-nova/wed-react-native/node_modules/react-native/local-cli/bundle/output/prepack.js:23:25)
>       at saveBundle (/Users/huangjunjie/Documents/Work/wed-iphone-nova/wed-react-native/node_modules/react-native/local-cli/bundle/buildBundle.js:19:12)
>       at /Users/huangjunjie/Documents/Work/wed-iphone-nova/wed-react-native/node_modules/react-native/local-cli/bundle/buildBundle.js:72:16
>       at tryCallOne (/Users/huangjunjie/Documents/Work/wed-iphone-nova/wed-react-native/node_modules/promise/lib/core.js:37:12)
>       at /Users/huangjunjie/Documents/Work/wed-iphone-nova/wed-react-native/node_modules/promise/lib/core.js:123:15

I don't know where is wrong? Can anyone tell me why?

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the `--prepack true` flag at the end which enables the experimental prepack preprocessor.